# Average of nested objects values in Javascript

Tags: javascript, lodash

This seems embarrassing to ask, but I'm unsure where to go from here.

I have an array of nested objects and I would like to create a new object that has the average from the original array.

```
const _ = require(`lodash`)

const data = JSON.parse(`
[
  {
      "thingOne": {
          "numberOne": 1758,
          "numberTwo": 97
      },
      "thingTwo": {
          "numberOne": 1758,
          "numberTwo": 97
      }
  },
  {
      "thingOne": {
          "numberOne": 1968,
          "numberTwo": 95
      },
      "thingTwo": {
          "numberOne": 2010,
          "numberTwo": 95
      }
  }
]`)

const results = {}

_.each(data, (value, key) => {
  _.each(value, (value, key) => {
    if (key in results) {
      results[key] = {
        numberOne: results[key].numberOne + value.numberOne,
        numberTwo: results[key].numberTwo + value.numberTwo,
      }
    } else {
      results[key] = value
    }
  })
})

console.log(results)
```

I can do this to sum up the array into a new object, but am unsure what to do from here. Do I need to loop this all over again to create an average? Any help appreciated (and I'm not required to use lodash, if there's a simpler answer).

Here's what I'm expected to get in the end:

```
const expected = {
  thingOne: {
    numberOne: 1863,
    numberTwo: 96,
  },
  thingTwo: {
    numberOne: 1884,
    numberTwo: 96,
  },
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Noticed that you've used lodash you can take advantage of `_.mergeWith()`:

From lodash [DOCS](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#mergeWith):

```
_.mergeWith(object, sources, customizer)
```

> This method is like _.merge except that it accepts customizer which is
>   invoked to produce the merged values of the destination and source
>   properties. If customizer returns undefined, merging is handled by the
>   method instead. The customizer is invoked with six arguments:
>   (objValue, srcValue, key, object, source, stack).

In our case, our *customizer* method retrieves the average, instead of merging values.

```js
const data = JSON.parse(`
[
  {
      "thingOne": {
          "numberOne": 1758,
          "numberTwo": 97
      },
      "thingTwo": {
          "numberOne": 1758,
          "numberTwo": 97
      }
  },
  {
      "thingOne": {
          "numberOne": 1968,
          "numberTwo": 95
      },
      "thingTwo": {
          "numberOne": 2010,
          "numberTwo": 95
      }
  }
]`);


const getAvg = (data) => _.mergeWith({}, ...data, (a, b) => {
  if(_.isNumber(b)) {
    return ((b || 0) / data.length) + (_.isNumber(a) ? (a || 0) : 0);
  }
});


console.log(getAvg(data));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Credit for the implementation of the `getAvg` function goes to [Ori Drori](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43925076), who originally posted it in answer to a related question.

Comment: Thank you. I can't say I entirely understand this, but it does seem to work.

Comment: @duffn The customizer acts as a reducer on the array of values for EACH field, after merging.

Comment: @Mr.Polywhirl the docs are quite clear about it: "If customizer returns undefined, merging is handled by the method instead". Look at the internal method https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/master/.internal/baseMerge.js

Comment: It appears that you have copied some of the code from [Ori Drori's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43924249/dynamically-calculate-the-average-for-a-nested-collection-using-lodash/43925076#43925076). Please make sure to *cite your sources* when you borrow code from someone else's answer.

Comment: Hi @CodyGray, I've included the credits in original post, deleted by mistake when updating with docs, thanks

Answer (score 1):

Here is an explanation of what is going on in Mosè Raguzzini's code.

The code is essentially performing a rolling-average of every value as it comes in.

e.g. `PREV_VAL += CURR_VAL / TOTAL_VALS`

See: [*How to calculate moving average without keeping the count and data-total?*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16757630/1762224)

```js
const DEBUG = true;

var data = [{
  "thingOne": { "numberOne": 1758, "numberTwo": 97 },
  "thingTwo": { "numberOne": 1758, "numberTwo": 97 }
}, {
  "thingOne": { "numberOne": 1968, "numberTwo": 95 },
  "thingTwo": { "numberOne": 2010, "numberTwo": 95 }
}, {
  "thingOne": { "numberOne":    1, "numberTwo":  1 },
  "thingTwo": { "numberOne":    1, "numberTwo":  1 }
}];

console.log(calculateRollingAverage(data));

/**
 * Calculates a rolling-average of data.
 * 
 * PREV_VAL += CURR_VAL / TOTAL_VALS
 * 
 * @param data {object[]} - an array of data objects
 * @return Returns the rolling-average of each data objects' fields.
 */
function calculateRollingAverage(data) {
  return _.mergeWith({}, ...data, (prev, curr) => {
    if (DEBUG) {
      console.log(`prev = ${JSON.stringify(prev)} | curr = ${JSON.stringify(curr)}`);
    }
    if (_.isNumber(curr)) {
      let p = _.isNumber(prev) ? (prev || 0) : 0, c = (curr || 0) / data.length;
      if (DEBUG) {
        console.log(`avg => ${p} + (${curr} / ${data.length}) = ${p + c}`);
      }
      return p + c;
    }
  });
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { top: 0; max-height: 100% !important; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You run through the keys and solve like below.

```js
const data = JSON.parse(`
[
  {
      "thingOne": {
          "numberOne": 1758,
          "numberTwo": 97
      },
      "thingTwo": {
          "numberOne": 1758,
          "numberTwo": 97
      }
  },
  {
      "thingOne": {
          "numberOne": 1968,
          "numberTwo": 95
      },
      "thingTwo": {
          "numberOne": 2010,
          "numberTwo": 95
      }
  }
]`);

let expected = {};
data.forEach(function(thing) {

    let parentKeys = Object.keys(thing);
    
    parentKeys.forEach(function(parentKey) {
    
        if (!expected.hasOwnProperty(parentKey)) {
        
            expected[parentKey] = {};
        }
        
        let expectedParent = expected[parentKey];
        let parent = thing[parentKey];
        let childKeys = Object.keys(parent);
        
        childKeys.forEach(function(childKey) {
            
            if (!expectedParent.hasOwnProperty(childKey)) {
        
                 expectedParent[childKey] = 0;
            }
        
            expectedParent[childKey] += parent[childKey] /                    parentKeys.length;
        });
    });
});

console.log(expected);
```

Comment: I think you are doing a running-average instead of an overall average.